# Magento Admin Permission Role Issue

Tags: magento, permissions, resources, role

In magento , I can create a sub-admin giving access to limited resources. But if I allow any sub-admin to create new sub-admin user then he is allowed to give all the access to the new sub-admin even which are not available to him..

Sub-admin should only allow the access, whatever he is holding.

For eg. : If sub admin is not having access to reports, he can not allow the report access to the other user he is creating from his access.

Any Suggestions.. ?

Comment: If you are giving User & Role access to sub-admin, then he/she can create new user as well as role. Magento doesn't check it's own access level. According to your requirement, you have override admin Permission module.

Comment: Thanks.. I also thought the same..

Answer (score 0):

You can change into table **admin_role**, change the number in **parent_id** and **tree_level** columns of your user.

[image]